# React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by TimelineDrawer. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

i'm trying to solve one error in my application that is appering in the console. You can check the error in the image bellow.

[image]

and my component called TimelineDrawer has the following code:

```
import { faTimes } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { ButtonIcon } from 'commons/ButtonIcon';
import { Loader } from 'commons/Loader';
import { Text } from 'commons/Text';
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from 'hooks';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { setNewCounter } from 'store/slices/timelineChannelServiceModel';
import { EngineSchedule } from 'types/engineSchedulesTypes';
import { SpecificMessages } from './components/SpecificMessages';
import { TimelineAccordion } from './components/TimelineAccordion';
import { TimelineBox } from './components/TimelineBox';
import { useStyles } from './materialStyles';
import {
  StCloseButtonWrapper,
  StContentBoxWrapper,
  StDescriptionText,
  StDrawer,
  StHeaderAndActionCloseWrapper,
  StHeaderTag,
  StHeaderText,
  StHeaderTextWrapper,
  StInfoDescriptionWrapper,
  StPriorityHeader,
  StPriorityNumber,
  StTitleText,
  StWrapper,
} from './styled';

interface DrawerProps {
  open: boolean;
  close: () => void;
  schedule: EngineSchedule;
}

export interface BreacrumbSpecificMessagesInterface {
  priority: number;
  channel: string;
}

export default function TimelineDrawer({
  open,
  close,
  schedule,
}: DrawerProps): JSX.Element {
  const customMaterialStyles = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState<boolean | string>(false);
  const [showSpecificMessages, setShowSpecificMessages] = useState(false);
  const [channelId, setChannelId] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [scheduleChannelId, setScheduleChannelId] = useState<number | null>(
    null,
  );
  const [breadCrumbSpecificMessages, setBreadCrumbSpecificMessages] = useState(
    {} as BreacrumbSpecificMessagesInterface,
  );
  const { engineScheduleTimelineDetails, loading } = useAppSelector(
    (store) => store.engineScheduleTimelineDetails,
  );

  const channelPriorityDescription =
    'O sistema acionará os canais somente do maior nível de prioridade para os quais o destinatário possuir pelo menos um contato correspondente';

  const handleShowSpecificMessages = (
    priority: number,
    channel: string,
    channelId: number,
    scheduleChannelId: number,
  ) => {
    setBreadCrumbSpecificMessages({
      priority,
      channel,
    });
    setChannelId(channelId);
    setScheduleChannelId(scheduleChannelId);
    setShowSpecificMessages(true);
    dispatch(setNewCounter(null));
  };

  const handleCloseDrawer = () => {
    setShowSpecificMessages(false);
    setExpanded(false);
    close();
  };

  function headerTextValue(scheduleReference: number) {
    return scheduleReference === 1
      ? 'do Vencimento'
      : scheduleReference === 2
      ? 'da Entrada'
      : scheduleReference === 3
      ? 'da Devolução'
      : scheduleReference === 5
      ? 'da Promessa'
      : '';
  }

  return (
    <StDrawer anchor='right' open={open} onClose={handleCloseDrawer}>
      <StWrapper>
        {showSpecificMessages ? (
          <SpecificMessages
            specificMessagesDescription='Com base em um atributo da sua base de dados para um publico especifico dentro da base'
            setShowSpecificMessages={setShowSpecificMessages}
            schedule={schedule}
            headerTextValue={headerTextValue(schedule.reference)}
            handleCloseDrawer={handleCloseDrawer}
            breadCrumbSpecificMessages={breadCrumbSpecificMessages}
            channelId={channelId as number}
            scheduleChannelId={scheduleChannelId as number}
          />
        ) : (
          <>
            <StHeaderAndActionCloseWrapper>
              <StHeaderTextWrapper>
                <StHeaderTag $reference={schedule.reference} />
                <StHeaderText
                  value={`D${schedule.order} ${headerTextValue(
                    schedule.reference,
                  )}`}
                  size='title'
                />
              </StHeaderTextWrapper>
              <StCloseButtonWrapper>
                <ButtonIcon
                  icon={faTimes}
                  onHoverColor='darkBlue'
                  backgroundColor='transparent'
                  onHoverBackgroundColor='transparent'
                  tooltipTitle='Fechar'
                  tooltip
                  onButtonClick={handleCloseDrawer}
                />
              </StCloseButtonWrapper>
            </StHeaderAndActionCloseWrapper>
            <StInfoDescriptionWrapper>
              <StTitleText size='highlight' value='Priorização de canal' bold />
              <StDescriptionText
                size='label'
                value={channelPriorityDescription}
              />
            </StInfoDescriptionWrapper>
            {loading ? (
              <Loader variant='bigLoader' />
            ) : (
              <StContentBoxWrapper>
                {/* sort para garantir que será sempre exibido ordem de prioridade correta */}
                {engineScheduleTimelineDetails?.priorities
                  .slice()
                  .sort((a, b) => (a.priority > b.priority ? 1 : -1))
                  .map((element, key) => (
                    <TimelineBox
                      key={key}
                      showBorder
                      marginBottom={24}
                      borderRadius={12}
                      padding='16px'
                    >
                      <StPriorityHeader>
                        <StPriorityNumber
                          size='label'
                          value={`${element?.priority}ª`}
                        />
                        <Text size='label' color='blue500' value='Prioridade' />
                      </StPriorityHeader>
                      <div className={customMaterialStyles?.accordionRoot}>
                        {element?.engineScheduleChannels?.map((item, index) => {
                          return (
                            <TimelineAccordion
                              item={item}
                              key={item.id}
                              index={index}
                              element={element}
                              handleShowSpecificMessages={
                                handleShowSpecificMessages
                              }
                              expanded={expanded}
                              setExpanded={setExpanded}
                            />
                          );
                        })}
                      </div>
                    </TimelineBox>
                  ))}
              </StContentBoxWrapper>
            )}
          </>
        )}
      </StWrapper>
    </StDrawer>
  );
}
```

how can i solve this problem? I tried many things with no success.. :/

I'm expecting to solve this problem that is appearing in my console browser

Comment: Error does not appear to be in the code you posted, it's probably in one of those custom hooks. The error message is referencing the use of `useEffect` and `useContext` which are not in your posted code.

Comment: most likey useEffect and useMemo are being called  conditinally inside one of the components in the JSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by" occurs when we conditionally call a hook or return early before all hooks have run. To solve the error, move all hooks to the top level of the function component and don't use hooks inside conditions.

Only Call Hooks from React Functions

Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions

Best Practice

use eslint for lint your code avoid geting React Hooks Rules errors

install package with npm or yarn:

> npm install eslint-plugin-react-hooks --save-dev